# Openam 14.8.1 unable to login SSO saml2 ldap auth

Tags: single-sign-on

Openam 14.8.1, I am unable to login with a new login page after a previous login page session timeout using SSO saml2 ldap auth

I expect the user to login instead of being loged out.

It work as expexted after cleaning browser data and open a fresh new login page!!